# Differential equation. Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider the following differential equation:

$t(1-t) x'' + (p-(p+2)tx' - px = 0$

a) Prove that t=0 is a singular regula point for that equation. Prove that if $p \notin\mathbb{Z}$ there are two linearly independent soutions in form of Frobenius series convergent for $|t| < 1$.

b) Find the general solution of the given equation, expressed in terms of elementary functions when $p \notin \mathbb{Z}$

c) Solve the equation for $p=1$

Comment: Is the DEQ written correctly? As written, the $p's$ cancel out.

Comment: @Trollkemada: You lose one ) sign in your ODE, where should it be placed?